# AWS CLI restore-from-cluster-snapshot doesn't find snapshot in account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cli

I'm trying to restore a cluster from a snapshot using

```
aws redshift restore-from-cluster-snapshot --cluster-identifier my-cluster
--snapshot-identifier my-identifier  --profile my-profile --region my-region
```

But I'm receiving

```
An error occurred (ClusterSnapshotNotFound) when calling
 the RestoreFromClusterSnapshot operation: Snapshot not found: my-identifier
```

I checked the available snapshots using

```
aws redshift describe-cluster-snapshots --profile my-profile --region my-region
```

And `my-identifier` appears as available snapshot.

Entering via Redshift console I'm also able to see the snapshots and was able to restore it from the UI.

Does anybody have any clues ?

P.S.: Not sure if it's relevant, but it's a snapshot from another account that I shared with the account where I'm trying to restore the cluster

Comment: Do you have the same rights when using the CLI as when in the console?  Like the ability to read the snapshot.

Comment: Yes. I used the same profile to check the UI

Comment: Have you tried the --owner-acount?  From the help page: "--owner-account (string)
          The AWS customer account  used  to  create  or  copy  the  snapshot.
          Required if you are restoring a snapshot you do not own, optional if
          you own the snapshot."

Comment: Thanks, Bill ! It worked. I find it odd tho, that I used to execute the exact same command without providing the owner account.

Comment: Good to hear.  It's security thing.  The creating account is needed to decrypt the snapshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the owner account number when restoring to enable Redshift to decrypt the shared snapshot.

```sh
aws redshift restore-from-cluster-snapshot  \
  --profile myAwsCliProfile  \
  --snapshot-identifier mySnapshotName \

  --owner-account 012345678910  \

  --cluster-identifier my-new-redshift-cluster \
  --number-of-nodes 6     \
  --node-type ra3.16xlarge   \
  --port 5439   \
  --region us-east-1   \
  --availability-zone us-east-1d \
  --cluster-subnet-group-name default\
  --availability-zone-relocation  \
  --no-publicly-accessible \
  --maintenance-track-name CURRENT
```